# What implications has the attribute "owner" of a file/folder?

Tags: windows-10, permissions

When using windows explorer, I can change the "details" of the folder, like "date", "size", and I one of the possible details to be shown is "owner". What does the owner of file can do that others can't? It's a shorthand for the operating system to give certain permissions? Which permissions?

Answer (score 2):

The owner of a file or folder is the user who has complete and full control over that file or folder in terms of being able to grant access to the resource, and also allow other users to take over the ownership of a file or folder. This is often, but not always, the creator of the file or folder and is governed by the location of where the file or folder is first created. Typically, the creator of the file or folder is, by default, initially designated as the owner. Ownership of a file or folder may be taken by an administrator, any user with Take ownership permission on the object in question or any user with the right to Restore Files and Directories which by default includes members of the Backup Operators group.

Answer (score 1):

The owner of a file is always able to read and write that file's access control list. Technically speaking, it gives you the `READ_CONTROL` and `WRITE_DAC` [standard access rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379607(v=vs.85).aspx). Being the owner does not automatically grant you other abilities, but you can grant them to yourself since you can change the file's permissions.

Note that being the owner and thereby having complete access to the ACL doesn't give you *complete* control over the file. For example, you can't forcibly transfer ownership to somebody else unless you have `SeRestorePrivilege` (which comes with membership in Administrators or Backup Operators). Also, [you cannot view the SACL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379321(v=vs.85).aspx) (the auditing properties) without having `SeSecurityPrivilege`, which is by default an administrator-only privilege.